# php get method arguments default values

Tags: php, methods, arguments

I want to get list of methods inside a class as well as their arguments and default values. how can I do that? below is the code that I used:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass($className);
$methods = [];
foreach($class->getMethods() as $method){
   if($method->class == $className && $method->name != '__construct' ){
       $obj = [];
       $obj['controller'] = $className;
       $obj['action'] = $method->name;
       $obj['params'] = array_map(function($value){return $value->name;}, $method->getParameters());
       $methods[] = $obj;
   }
}
```

The sample result of above code is like:

```
 Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [controller] => Controller,
        [action] => function,
        [params] => Array
        (
            [0] => offset,
            [1] => limit
        )
    )
 )
```

How can I get function arguments default values?

Comment: your title should be more specific and well written. because i mistook it as an another post when i saw the title

Comment: You get a list of ReflectionParameter objects by using `getParameters()`. You can get the defaults from those objects using class' [getDefaultValue](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php) method.

Comment: IDK if this is exaclty what you're looking for, but his might be helpful: http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2015/05/logging-class-usage-in-php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `array_map` function for the parameters, you can insert a check whether the parameter has a default value using `->isDefaultValueAvailable()` and if so - list it using `->getDefaultValue()`. See the example below based on your code and change it according to your needs.

Instead of

```
$obj['params'] = array_map(
  function($value){return $value->name;}, 
  $method->getParameters()
);
```

Use

```
$obj['params'] = array_map(
  function($value){
    return $value->name.
      ($value->isDefaultValueAvailable() ? '='.$value->getDefaultValue() : '');
  },
  $method->getParameters()
);
```